# Add custom field to blog post.aspx page (SP 2010)

Tags: column, custom, blog

I have changed the default look of the post.aspx and default.aspx page for the OOB SharePoint Blog 2010 by using custom XSL file based on the OOB one only changed the option to show custom logo in the left column instead of the date table.

My question now is this. How can I add on my post.aspx page a custom defined column field (multi line). I wont to have this new field (text) to show just under the default text that was posted for that blog post but before the comments?

So for exp, we have a blog post (thats basicly a question), then i would like to see the response field (that's the custom defined one) and then default comment section?

I have to note that I'm not experienced with coding, but any guidelines how to and where to define that new field would be great.

Can this be done by only editing aspx/xsl files or not?

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straight-forward guide. The issue is to show XSL code, which is ghosted. You can show them by touching XSL-driven layout in WYSIWYG editor of SharePoint Designer 2010, but Post.aspx requires ID parameter to show a Post `XsltListViewWebpart`.

1. Open `Post.aspx` on `All Files/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx` in SharePoint Designer 2010
2. There is no XSL code. It's ghosted now.
3. Find `<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>`. Remind that there are multiple webparts. Use description to indicate right one. It should say "Use the Posts list for posts in this blog."
4. When you select any inbound of the webpart, List View Tools ribbon shows on the menu. (see screen grab)
5. Select `Design` tab of `List View Tools`
6. Check `Sample Data`, then `XsltListViewWebPart` have sample data
7. Now, you can select any of XSLT area in WYSIWYG editor. When you click any, XSL code will be automatically added on code editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.henryong.com/2011/10/28/adding-sharepoint-social-rating-stars-to-the-homepage-of-sharepoint-blog-sites/

May be this blog can help .

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: the above post only addresses the default/home page of the blog site, which uses the Posts ListViewWebPart.  The question in this thread asked about the Post.aspx page.